# how to set the html selected option value as selected in each page when including the same code in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok I have a page name "my_file.html" with the code,

```
<script> //Beahvior on change
jQuery("#selectBox").change(function() {
document.getElementById("selectBox").value =$( "#selectBox).val();
          location = $("#selectBox option:selected").val();
 });
</script>

  <!--A select html tag --> 
  <div class="block2">
  <select id="selectBox">
  <option value="check.html">Check.html</option>
  <option value="going.html">Going.html</option>
  <option value="check123.html">Check123.html </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Now this page(my_file.html) is loaded externally into the three files "check.html" ,"going.html" and "check123.html" with Jquery.Ok now I manually type the directory of "check.html" and the page is loaded,when selecting "going.html" from the option list the page going.html is loaded with the 'my_file.html' content but the option 'value="going.html"'is not mark as selected.The option list simply shows "check.html" as the selected option.This same behavior happens on selecting 'check123.html' option too.I also cannot load the 'check.html' page because it is already set as selected.

I have been trying to figure out the solution of this problem but to no avail,any help would be good.

If you want to know what I want to achieve go to this link http://readcomiconline.to/Comic/The-Walking-Dead/Issue-1?id=1715 
Below the navigation bar you will see the "Issue" select option tag and when you choose any chapter from the drop down list,that issue is loaded and also the selected 'Issue' is set as selected.

Answer (score 0):

that site seems use "get" to achieve that,

in the top of my_file.html

```
<?php
     $selectedCheck = $_GET['selected'];
?>
```

and in your div

```
<div class="block2">
    <select id="selectBox">
        <option value="check.html" <?php echo (($selectedCheck == 'check.html') ? 'selected':'');?>Check.html</option>
        <option value="going.html" <?php echo (($selectedCheck == 'going.html') ? 'selected':'');?>>Going.html</option>
        <option value="check123.html" <?php echo (($selectedCheck == 'check123.html') ? 'selected':'');?>>Check123.html </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

it maybe not a smart way but it work and pretty easy to use :)

or maybe just add a default option like "Please choose one" and set it as selected, then whatever u selected the select will mark "Please choose one" selected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `selectedIndex` would do what you want:

```
document.getElementById("selectBox").selectedIndex = 2;
```

This way you can control what option is selected.